# IIS 10.0 rewrite URL only for certain domains

Tags: .net, url, iis, url-rewriting

I have two domains pointing into one web application:

**https://domain1.com** and **https://domain2.com**

I want to make a redirect for https://domain2.com to https://domain2.com/domain2Login/

The rewrite should not affect domain1 and should be considered for both http and https.

I tried

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect domain2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="domain2.com" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="domain2.com/domain2Login" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The rewrite doesnt activate, when I go to the url https://domain2.com or http://domain2.com. Is there anything obvious I am missing here? I also tried different match conditions based on https and http but that didnt work either.

Let me know if you need more info and thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the URL rewrite extension?

Comment: @Charlieface yes, I installed it from here: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite. I also see the rewrite module in the IIS window

Comment: Mistake 1 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: @LexLi that's the solution thank you very much, if you like you can add that as anaswer and I'll accept it

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question